# How to install Ubuntu 15.04 on UEFI system with SSD

Tags: partitioning, 15.04, uefi, ssd, gpt

I am thinking about to install 15.04 to my PC which has the following [specifications](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12418704/):

Previously I have installed 14.04 on this system in UEFI mode and the entry of Ubuntu is still shown in UEFI. I know I can remove that entry with efibootmgr but I am afraid to use that because of the unknown (maybe fatal) consequences.

My question:

- [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12425032/) install method is correct for my system?

Thanks for your kindness!

**UPDATE:**

Answer posted below.

Armand

Comment: Install it the same way as you installed 14.04. But it is better to leave 14.04 LTS as it is. And please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it was a long ago I have installed 14.04 so unfortunately I can't remember some steps. I would like to please you if I miss something please let me know that.

As far as I remember I have done the following:

1. created an uefi usb drive on windows (at that time on 8.1, probably with rufus, so i have selected gpt in that)

Comment: *Sorry for my half-edited comment there are the steps I would do on 15.04. Please check it, and let me know if I'm wrong. I'm afraid of the wearing level of my SSD, so thazs why I ask you at first.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12418626/

Comment: [Summarized a bit more. I hope now my question can be reopened]

Comment: [Question resolved]

Comment: I voted to reopen to post the solution as an answer.

Comment: @Pilot6

Thanks. Without the ability to post pictures it will not be the most interesting thing to read, but i will not repine. Maybe for some user it will contain new and (maybe) helpful information and that is the point. :)

Comment: Voted to reopen too!  Then @ArmandBozsik can cut-paste from the question to the answer section and remove [closed] from the title...  **;-)**

Comment: The question is now reopened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A short how to how I installed Ubuntu on my system:**

1. Created an UEFI GPT pendrive with Rufus
2. Since I was using Windows 10 I have disabled “Fast Startup”, checked BitLocker is off and turned off hibernation (powercfg /h off).
3. Disabled Fastboot in UEFI
4. Also disabled Secure Boot (Switched to “Other OS”)
5. Booted from UEFI pendrive.
6. Created an 1024MB fat32 primary partition (with the label “EFI”) with a free space of 1MiB preceding
7. I have 16GB of RAM so I created a 16384MB swap partition with linux-swap file system.
8. The rest (without the 10-15% provisioning space) went for / (root) with ext4.
9. Agreed the UEFI install warning
10. Then the install method was the same like on a BIOS machine.
11. I have installed fglrx (fglrx-updates) for my Radeon R9 270X

**This step is necessary if you have an ASUS Xonar sound card!**

11. Turned volume to maximum in alsamixer for my Xonar DS in Master Front

P.S.: Alignment and TRIM is automatically enabled on newer Samsung SSDs.